# Error: "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'zipp>=0.5' distribution was not found and is required by importlib-metadata"

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I encountered this issue today. Trying to make a buildozer build of my kivy-python script. However, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI0CP.png) happens.
I've got the latest version of zipp <0.6.0>, and I am running on Elementary OS Hera.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install `zipp`? Does it show in the output of `pip list`?

Comment: @jordanm pip list outputs zipp -> 0.6.0